# How to write content and fetch that content from Azure Wiki by using Python Script?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-active-directory, azure-pipelines

How to write content and fetch that content from **Azure Wiki** by using **Python Script**?

I used Azure wiki API for making connections but I don't know how to fetch the content from there.

And API is:
GET [https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/wiki/wikis/{wikiIdentifier}?api-version=6.0](https://dev.azure.com/%7Borganization%7D/%7Bproject%7D/_apis/wiki/wikis/%7BwikiIdentifier%7D?api-version=6.0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your requirement, you need to use Rest API to get the content from Wiki.

I suggest that you can use Rest API: [Pages - Get](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wiki/pages/get?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0#get-page-as-json-with-content)

For example:

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/fabrikam/{project}/_apis/wiki/wikis/{wikiIdentifier}/pages?path=/SamplePage129&includeContent=True&api-version=5.0
```

Use Python to run the Rest API:

```
import requests
import base64

pat = 'PAT'
authorization = str(base64.b64encode(bytes(':'+pat, 'ascii')), 'ascii')

headers = {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': 'Basic '+authorization
}

response = requests.get(
    url="https://dev.azure.com/fabrikam/{project}/_apis/wiki/wikis/{wikiIdentifier}/pages?path=/SamplePage129&includeContent=True&api-version=5.0", headers=headers)
print(response)
```